# Ignore Hidden Excel worksheets in Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

How do you ignore hidden worksheets when looping through the worksheets in powershell?

Lets say I have a loop like this

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$excel.visible = $False 
$excel.displayalerts=$False 
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelPath) 
foreach ($ws in $workbook.Worksheets)
{
#do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($ws.Visible -eq 0) {
    # Hidden
    } else {
    # Visible
    }
```